# Eloquent: check if relationship has certain conditions

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a model `Survey` which is related to `hasOne`  another model `Installation` which is related to `hasMany` another model `Assignment`.
So i defined a `hasManyThrough` relationship like this

```
public function assignments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class,Installation::class);
    }
```

I want to write a query to fetch any `Survey` where the `Assignments` associated with the survey does not have an assignment.type of 0,1,2,3 and 4.

i.e.
Each survey should have an 5 assignments with records

```
Survey => [
[Assignment => [type = 0]]
[Assignment => [type = 1]]
[Assignment => [type = 2]]
[Assignment => [type = 3]]
[Assignment => [type = 4]]
]
```

I tried this query

```
 $schedulables = Survey::whereNotNull('installer_id')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                        return $query->raw('SELECT * FROM assignments,installations where assignments.installation_id = installations.id and installations.survey_id = surveys.id and assignments.type= 1');
                    })
                    ->orwhereNotExists(function ($query) {
                        return $query->raw('SELECT * FROM assignments,installations where assignments.installation_id = installations.id and installations.survey_id = surveys.id and assignments.type= 2');
                    })
                    ->orwhereNotExists(function ($query) {
                        return $query->raw('SELECT * FROM assignments,installations where assignments.installation_id = installations.id and installations.survey_id = surveys.id and assignments.type= 3');
                    })
                    ->orwhereNotExists(function ($query) {
                        return $query->raw('SELECT * FROM assignments,installations where assignments.installation_id = installations.id and installations.survey_id = surveys.id and assignments.type= 4');
                    });

            })
            ->with('customer', 'installer', 'installation')
            ->latest('updated_at')->get();
```

Please any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was to create these relationships in the `Survey` model

```
 public function assignment_outdoor(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class,Installation::class)
            ->where('assignments.type',1)
            ->where('assignments.status',2);
    }
    public function assignment_indoor(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class,Installation::class)
            ->where('assignments.type',2)
            ->where('assignments.status',2);
    }
    public function assignment_testing_activation(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class,Installation::class)
            ->where('assignments.type',3)
            ->where('assignments.status',2);
    }
    public function assignment_lm_splicing(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class,Installation::class)
            ->where('assignments.type',4)
            ->where('assignments.status',2);
    }
```

And then built the query using `doesntHave` and `ordoesntHave`.

```
$schedulables = Survey::when($installer_filter, function ($query, $installer_filter) {
            return $query->where('installer_id', $installer_filter);
        })
            ->whereNotNull('installer_id')
//actual solution
            ->where(function ($query) {
                return $query

                    ->doesntHave('assignment_outdoor')
                    ->orDoesntHave('assignment_indoor')
                    ->orDoesntHave('assignment_testing_activation')
                    ->orDoesntHave('assignment_lm_splicing');

            })
//end
            ->doesntHave('network_job_order_customer')
            ->with('customer', 'installer', 'installation')
            ->latest('updated_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and [whereNotIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) to achieve what you're after:

```
$schedulables = Survey
    ::with('customer', 'installer', 'installation')
    ->whereNotNull('installer_id')
    ->whereHas('assignments', function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotIn('type', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
    })
    ->latest('updated_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please include the relevant documentation in your answer rather than just linking to it. It helps if the link goes dead.